# how to handle list that contains emoji in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, emoji

I've been making function that takes list that has only emoji and transfer it to utf-8 unicode and return the unocode list . My current code seems to take multiple args and return error . I'm new to handling emoji . Could you give me some tips ??

```
main.py

def encode_emoji(emoji_list):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(emoji_list)):
        emoji = str(emoji_list[i])
        d_ord = format(ord(":{}:","#08x").format(emoji))
        result.append(str(d_ord))
        break
    return result 


encode_emoji(["","",""])
```

```
Result of above code

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    encode_emoji(["","",""])
  File "main.py", line 5, in encode_emoji
    d_ord = format(ord(":{}:","#08x").format(emoji))
TypeError: ord() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea of how you intend to get the utf-8 encoding of an emoji with this line:

```
d_ord = format(ord(":{}:","#08x").format(emoji))
```

As the error message says,  `ord` would take a single argument: a 1-character long string, and return an integer. Now, even if the code above would be placed so that the value returned by `ord(emoji)` was correctly concatenated to `0x8` as a prefix, that would basically be an specific representation of a basically random hexadecimal number - not the utf-8 sequence for the emoji.

To encode some text into utf-8, just call the `encode` method of the string itself.

Also, in Python, one almost never will use the `for... in range(len(...))` pattern, as `for` is well designed to iterate over any sequence or iterable with no side effects.

Your code also have a loosely placed `break` statement that would stop any processing after the first character.

Without using the list-comprehension syntax, a function to encode emoji as utf-8 byte strings is just:

```py
def encode_emoji(emoji_list):
   result = []
   for part in emoji_list:
       result.append(part.encode("utf-8"))
```

Once you get more acquainted with the language and understand comprehensions, it is just:

```py
def encode_emoji(emoji_list):
    return [part.encode("utf-8") for part in emoji_list)]
```

Now, given the `#8` pattern in your code, it may be that you have misunderstood what utf-8 means, and are simply trying to write down the emoji's as valid HTML encoded char references - that later will be embedded in text that will be encoded to utf-8.

In that case, you have indeed to call `ord(emoji)` to get its codepoint, but then represent the resulting number as hexadecimal, and replace the leading `0x` Python's `hex` call yields with `#`:

```py
def encode_emoji(emoji_list):
    return [hex(ord(emoji)).replace("0x", "#") + ";" for emoji in emoji_list)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your invaluable advice . I should know more about  basic Python idea and unicode . I used this code ```d_ord = format(ord(":{}:","#08x").format(emoji))``` thoughtless cuz I usually check unicode with ```print(format(ord("::"),"#08x"))``` .  I tried your code and it works without any error .

Comment: I want the list like this 0x01F607, so firstly I tried to get the unicode list and I will make dictionary of them later on . I'm not sure my idea will work well but I will try with your advice . I appreciate it .

Answer (score 1):

> TypeError: ord() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

I think the error is self-explanatory. That function takes one argument, but you are passing it two:

1. ":{}"
2. "#08x"

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_ord.asp) some docs to read in case you need.

Comment: Thank you so much . I will check it again .